# Prove Edge connectivity for complete graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

From first principles prove that $κ(K_n) = κ′(K_n) = n − 1$ for every $n ≥ 2$.

$κ(K_n)$=Vertex connectivity

$κ′(K_n)$=Edge connectivity

I was told to show individually that $κ′(K_n)≤ n-1$ and $κ′(K_n)≥n-1$ where the former inequality is easier to prove than the latter. I've shown for the case $κ′(K_n)≥n-1 $ that the minimum amount of edges to disconnect the graph would be $n-1$ as isolating a single vertex would mean removing all the edges adjacent to it. But I don't know how to go about proving the first inequality, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you've actually proved the other way: since one way to disconnect the graph is to isolate a single vertex by removing $n-1$ adjacent edges, $\kappa'(K_n)\leq n-1$.

To show that $\kappa'(K_n)\geq n-1$, you need to prove that there's no way to disconnect the graph by removing fewer edges. Hint for this: suppose you remove some edges, and the remaining graph has two components with $a$ vertices and $n-a$ vertices. How many edges must have been removed (at least)?

Comment: For the minimum amount of edges to be removed, one of the components must contain only one vertex while the other component contains n-1 vertices. Then the amount of edges that must've been removed at least would be n-1 (the amount of edges removed initially added onto the edges removed when forming the 2 components). Am I thinking about this correctly?